# How do I block all ports except 22 and 80 in Fedora's iptables?

Tags: security, fedora, iptables, fedora-15

I am trying to only allow port 22 TCP/UDP and port 80 TCP/UDP from anywhere using Fedora 15 `iptables`, and all the rest will be never accessible nor scannable from a public network.

But it never works for me, at the end I turned it off because I am scared it will block me to access even the port 22 myself.

So, my question is, how can I do this in Fedora 15? Block all except for 22, 80 TCP/UDP?

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT

# Fresh start
iptables -F
# Localhost/ethernet 0 / yum installation allow
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state –state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# SSH
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp –dport 22 -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A INPUT -s aa.bb.aa.bb -d xx.yy.xx.yy -p tcp -m tcp –dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -d xx.yy.xx.yy -p tcp -m tcp –dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# other
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# show
iptables -L -v
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to edit firewall configuration on Fedora is using the `system-config-firewall` tool.  Just run `system-config-firewall` from X or `system-config-firewall-tui` and use the easy graphical/curses interface to set up your firewall rules.

Alternatively, the following `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` should do the trick:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Run `service iptables restart` when you are done.  (You could also use the above arguments with `iptables` and then run `service iptables save`).

Remember, if you have IPv6 connectivity you must do something similar in `/etc/sysconfig/ip6tables`.  `system-config-firewall` will automatically do this for you.